# How to get the modal dialog instance through the Bootstrap programmatic API?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

The scenario I'm trying to solve is to disable that the escape-button closes the dialog **AFTER** the modal has been instaniated (the dialog is set to a loading state). So in other words after I have instaniated my modal like this:

```
(this.$el).modal("show");
```

The user presses a submit button and the dialog is set to a loading state and I want to disable the escape-button since the user should not be able to close the dialog in this state.

I have tried this:

```
(this.$el).modal({ keyboard: false });
```

But it does not work, it seems that Bootstrap only reads those options when it instaniates the modal dialog...

So my question is if it is possible to get a hold of the actual bootstrap modal-instance to be able to change the options-object? According to the documentation it should be possible (or have I misunderstood the docs?), but I cannot figure out how.

Here is what it says in the documentation (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/): 
*If you'd like to get a particular plugin instance, retrieve it directly from an element:*

`$('[rel="popover"]').data('popover').`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I figured out how to get ahold of the modal dialog instance after some experimentation:

```
var bootstrapModalInstance = this.$el.data("bs.modal");
```

And then I could set the options on the instance like this:

```
bootstrapModalInstance.options.keyboard = !this.model.isSyncing;
```

Sadly enough, this did not solve the problem since the escape-key-event-listener is setup during the modal instaniation like this:

**From bootstrap.js**

```js
 Modal.prototype.escape = function () {
    if (this.isShown && this.options.keyboard) { // The event listener is setup on initalization 
      this.$element.on('keydown.dismiss.bs.modal', $.proxy(function (e) {
        e.which == 27 && this.hide() // !!! Does not check the instance options.keyboard flag status, so I had to add && this.options.keyboard here
      }, this))
    } else if (!this.isShown) {
      this.$element.off('keydown.dismiss.bs.modal')
    }
  }
```

And as I wrote in the code comment above adding the instance options.keyboard check in the event listener solved the issue.